# Unable to get device coarse location when testing with google mini device

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Hi I'm facing an issue that, i'm unable to get device coarse location when i tested on google mini device with same dialogflow account.I'm able to get user's  name but not device location. I'm frustrated regarding this issue.Please help to resolve this.

Here is my code,

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {dialogflow,Permission} = require('actions-on-google');
const app = dialogflow({
   clientId : 'xyz'
}); 
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  const options = {
    context: 'To locate you',
    permissions: ['NAME','DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION'],
  };
  conv.ask(new Permission(options));
});

app.intent('User_info',(conv, params, permissionGranted) => {
console.log(conv);
var location=conv.device.location;
console.log(location);
if(permissionGranted){
    const name = conv.user.name;
    console.log(name);
    var resp="you are located at"+conv.device.location.city;
    conv.ask(resp);
}else{
conv.close("sorry I'm unable to locate you right now. Okay bye now");
}
});

const expressApp=express().use(bodyParser.json())
expressApp.post('/',app);

expressApp.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION permission, and found an empty object in my Firebase logs where I expected to see the location.

Have you tried using DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION instead? Here's a sample how that works:

```
// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'Default Welcome Intent'.

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
  conv.ask(new Permission({
    context: 'Hi there, to get to know you better',
    permissions: ['NAME', 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION']
  }));
});

// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'actions_intent_PERMISSION'. If user
// agreed to PERMISSION prompt, then boolean value 'permissionGranted' is true.

app.intent('actions_intent_PERMISSION', (conv, params, permissionGranted) => {
  if (!permissionGranted) {
    conv.ask(`Ok, no worries. What's your favorite color?`);
    conv.ask(new Suggestions('Blue', 'Red', 'Green'));
  } else {
    console.log(conv);
    conv.data.userName = conv.user.name.given;
    conv.data.userLatitude = conv.device.location.coordinates.latitude;
    conv.data.userLongitude = conv.device.location.coordinates.longitude;
    conv.ask(`Thanks, ${conv.data.userName} at latitude ${conv.data.userLatitude} and longitude ${conv.data.userLongitude}. What's your favorite color?`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Max yes i tried DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION and able to get latitude and longitude.I'm also able to get Device coarse location.you have to set address for the device in google home app and then you can get location details.

Comment: Make sure that your phone wifi and device wifi should be same n/w so that you can able to set address in -->assistant-->Device name-->Device info-->Device address. Then you can test it with coarse @Max Wiederholt